# Replacing CHARMS with CiviCRM

Tags: evaluating-civicrm

Our school's fine arts dept (band, choir, orchestra, drama) uses Charms from [charmsoffice.com](http://charmsoffice.com).  Our Boosters for each of those groups also work with what is in Charms.  If nothing else I would like to use CiviCRM to enhance our fundraising and event coordination but would be interested to find if anybody else has transitioned from Charms before.

The major fund raiser for the entire department is selling advertisement space in a program book that is available at every fine arts event.  It is a huge effort - identifying potential customers/contributors/donors along with previous ones, assigning some to each of the students (ie. parents - ha), inputting their order (ie. ad-space info) such as size of ad, copy sample, and of course, payments.

Each group then has other fund raisers - many of them come up with new contributors but those never bubble up into a master list.

Anyway, Charms tracks students and parent/guardian relationship, faculty, events, volunteers, forms, communications, allows some merchandising, etc.  All of this is at a very minimal level.

FYI - I am located in Columbia, Missouri.  Looking for other CiviLians nearby.

Thanks,
John